# How protective diode protects transistor from breakdown?

Tags: transistors, diodes, npn, reverse-breakdown

Please, explain the process of breakdown; how exactly this protective diode protects the transistor?

In a Horowitz & Hill book, "The Art of Electronics", 2nd edition, in *"Chapter 2 - Transistors"* (page 68), i read the following:

> 2. Always remember that the base-emitter reverse breakdown voltage for silicon transistors is  small, quite often as little
>      as 6 volts. Input swings large enough to take the transistor
>      out of conduction can easily result in breakdown (with  consequent  degradation  of  hFE unless  a  protective diode is added
>      (Fig. 2.10).

Can't figure out how this diode protects the transistor from breakdown if the current goes only in one direction in this diode.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKA3LW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The diode is in place to protect the transistor from **reverse** \$V_{BE}\$ breakdown. If you reverse-bias the base-emitter junction by taking the transistor's emitter to ~\$6\rm{V}\$ more positive than the base, it will breakdown and begin conducting.

This reverse breakdown damages the base-emitter junction, causing a degradation in \$h_{FE}\$.

By placing a diode as shown, the reverse-bias voltage is limited to ~\$0.7\rm{V}\$; attempts to apply more voltage will be futile, since the diode will conduct a lot of current and prevent increased voltage. This protects the transistor's base-emitter junction.

Comment: Darn it, Zeke, you beat me to it. +1.