How to connect buffer with open drain to opto isolator circuit?
I'm trying to connect SN74LVC07A open drain output to Si87xx opto isolator circuit.
I have tried to connect 10k and 100k pullup and that did not seem to work. This is due to the current being limited. I'm worried that if I connect too low a resistor (say 100ohms) it will draw too much current. So I'm looking for suggestions on the correct way to wire this circuit.

The edited circuit will look like the following:

I'm adding the complete buffer circuit to show the 5V is derived from USB input with Schottky diode.

The newest iteration I moved to a 9V battery to see if I could at least get the circuit to register in software and I'm now getting what looks like signal.  I will probably end up using an external voltage that is higher such as vehicle power which is 12V.


You can buffer the 7407 output with npn transistor but why bother if 7407 can be replaced with push-pull output IC.

Can you please show an example picture with npn transistor, unfortunately I can't easily swap out the IC.  But I might be able to add a transistor inside the connector.

Page 3 of the 74LVC07 datasheet states maximum output voltage of +6.5V, which your last circuit, PNP and +9V supply, would violate, but I'm not sure if note 2 means you can get away with that.

Ah good to know and thanks for pointing this out, I will work on getting the voltage down.

The answer by Michal Podmanický is great, if you absolutely must use the 74'07, offering fast switching for PWM. However, that solution works right on the edge of the required operating voltages for your opto-isolator module.
My first suggestion, if you are not constrained to using the 74'07, is to use a device with push-pull output stages, such as the 74HC4050. Any such device could drive the isolator module's  input directly:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
According to the opto-isolator datasheet, the switching threshold is 1.8mA of LED current. Also, the datasheet hints (on page 6) that the forward voltage of the LED is about 2.3V at 3mA, which allows us to estimate LED current when a voltage is applied between SPEED+ and GND_A:

simulate this circuit
Without a more comprehensive graph of LED voltage vs. current, that's the best we can do, but this is adequate information to determine the minimum voltage that should be applied to achieve 1.8mA. By Ohm's law, accounting for R24 and R25:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &= \frac{V}{R} \\ \\
&= \frac{V_{IN}-V_{LED}}{R_{24}+R_{25}} \\ \\
1.8mA &= \frac{V_{IN}-2.3V}{920\Omega} \\ \\
V_{IN} &= 1.8mA \times 920\Omega + 2.3V \\ \\
&= 4.0V
\end{aligned}
$$
This is the voltage which is just enough to switch on the opto-isolator, but it assumes that LED voltage is well under the \$V_{F(ON)}=2.8V\$ maximum shown on page 4. That maximum is likely to have been determined for much greater current than 1.8mA, so I think this is a good estimate.
When using the transistor as an emitter follower (as you have in your design), the emitter will always be 0.7V or so below the base, so the best \$V_{IN}\$ you can hope to achieve is \$V_{IN} = +5V - 0.7V = +4.3V\$. This is operating precariously close to the 4V limit. On top of that, some voltage will be lost across the base (pull-up) resistor due to base current, which will lower base potential under +5V, so you must estimate this loss also. Assuming a worst-case transistor gain of \$\beta=50\$:

simulate this circuit
As you can see, base resistor R1 develops over 0.3V when passing sufficient current to produce 1.8mA from the emitter, illuminating the LED. This places the emitter at about 4V, as required by our estimates above, but it's right on the edge of functioning at all.
You'll need to use a base resistance much, much lower than 10kΩ for this to work. Try 4.7kΩ or less, instead. Even if that works, it's borderline, and I don't think this emitter follower solution is a good one.
You could use a PNP device in common-emitter configuration instead:

simulate this circuit
This ensures \$V_{IN} \approx 5V\$, which is well into safer territory, but it does invert the signal, so that a low potential at Y switches on the LED. To overcome that inversion, you could use a 74HC05 (or 74HCT05, for TTL compatible inputs).
Here's a much simpler way to achieve the same (inverted) behaviour without the need for any extra transistor (with a potential caveat):

simulate this circuit
I notice that both input channels (speed and forward) of your opto module have the same node name "GND_A" on the cathode side, which suggests they are physically connected. If that's the case, then you can't use this last solution.
If the inversion is a problem, and you are stuck with the 74'07, then you'll have to invert again, with a second transistor. You should still use the PNP to obtain the full 5V between SPEED+ and GND_A, but use another PNP device to invert:

simulate this circuit

Wow!  Very thorough response.  I tried the PNP circuit above and a similar thing happened, when I measure the 5V it has dropped to 0.5V?  Also the circuit should work but it doesn't register in the firmware I'm using.  Another caveat is that the 5V is actually 4.75V since it's dirived from USB 5V and has some lose by the time it get to the connector from an inline 1N5819HW Schottky diode.  I do have external 12V from the vehicle but I was trying to avoid having to add additional wiring.

I will add the complete schematic above.

@shotsimon I don't know what you mean by "dropped to 0.5V", or what dropped. Also, if you only have 4.75V, then you definitely can't use Michal's solution, or an emitter follower. It will have to be a push-pull or PNP stage.

When I measure the 5V with a DMM it has dropped to 0.5V, so maybe there is an error with my circuit.

BTW Inversion is not an issue.

I was wondering why the "much simpler" version wasn't the first answer... That's how I would assume an open-drain buffer would be applied.  I didn't catch the duplicate GND_A node names.

Because by grounding the A_GND with the open drain, would turn on both SPEED+ and FORWARD+ circuits.  I should clarify that FORWARD+ is already connected to a 5V input and works properly.

A buffered output of 7407:
The output voltage is 0.7V lower than +Vcc, so in case of Vcc=5V the output to opto is 4.3V.


I was just drawing this :)  What is the purpose of the diode and can it be ommited?

I think I found the answer here:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/164964/how-protective-diode-protects-transistor-from-breakdown

This diode pulls the opto input to ground when 7407 has output low. You can use just pull down resistor but this diode discharges the opto input faster through open collector of 7407. Also it doesn’t draw the current when 7407 has output High like pull-down resistor does.

I tried this circuit and unfortunately it did not work.  The power supply gets pulled down to 1.5V which leads me to think I'm missing something?  I will order and add the diode.

You have no pull-down without diode. You can add a 1k resistor between emitter and gnd if you hurry, but it will work for low frequency like 1kHz only.

I moved to the PNP solution below since it seemed like it had more margin for voltage, but thanks for this suggestion.

Based on the comments in the schematics the opto input requires 5V to 24V.
If you drive the high side pin with shunting current when LED needs to be off, indeed the pull-up would need to be 0 ohms to provide the required 5V, but then you can't use the shunt configuration.
Perhaps you should change to push-pull driver instead, or use the current driver as low side driver. But it depends if both optos have common cathode, you need to drive all cathodes separately but can simply wire 5V to the positive inputs. It may be impossible as the cathodes seem to have a common terminal, so you may need to switch to high side driving.

@shotsimon asking for products what to buy and from where is strictly off topic.

Do you have an example image of a push-pull circuit?

@shotsimon It would look identical to your drawing, the chip would just be of different type.
